# scroll to just below my div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got a div that expands on a click, sometimes its at the bottom of the page and its close to the bottom. What i want is that when its close to the bottom that it should scroll down just below it.

My solution so far is below. I get how to calculate the values and animate an all but i just dont get why my script wants to scroll to the bottom of the page, it just slams it to the bottom. Any ideas?

**EDIT**
Doh ofcause its gone scroll to the bottom. Question is how do i scroll so its just below my div by 10px? Im not suppose to say `scrollTop: total`

jquery

```
       var $ediv = $this.parent('div').find('.order-expand-row');
       var hDiv = $ediv.outerHeight();
       var oDiv = $ediv.offset().top;
       var wHeight = $(window).height();
       var total = hDiv + oDiv + 10;

       if (total >= wHeight) {                                   
          $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: total }, 600);
       }
```

Comment: [Your code work for me](http://jsfiddle.net/tqa6S/). Debug in your case to see what are the values.

Comment: I figure that the code is right itself, but its wrong for my situation. I need it to just scroll so the bottom of the window is just 10px below the `div`, right now it wants to scroll to the position off the divs bottom.

Comment: Yes, but your problem isn't in the code we see. Try to make a minimal fiddle having the problem. Did you check the values in debug ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well a cup of tea can do magic ;)

solved it by subtracting the `wHeight` from `total`, that got me the value i need to scroll to.
To clear it, what I needed was the position where i wanted to scroll to stop not where it should scroll to.

```
   var $ediv = $this.parent('div').find('.order-expand-row');
   var hDiv = $ediv.outerHeight();
   var oDiv = $ediv.offset().top;
   var wHeight = $(window).height();
   var total = hDiv + oDiv + 10;
   var scrollTo = total - wHeight; //the scroll position

   if (total >= wHeight) {                                   
      $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: scrollTo }, 600);
   }
```

Comment: OK... Thanks to have answered instead of just deleting the question.